# Uploading PDF file with certain name causes error

Tags: file-upload, library, pdf

I have quite interesting issue with our Sharepoint 2010 library. My colleague wanted to upload file with name "OC0372.pdf" but Sharepoint said

> "Oops, something went wrong, file not found". ID corelation: 6c2a209e-11c4-008e-5f38-cbdb119725c0

I tried to make a txt file with one word in it and rename it to "OC0372.txt" and I could upload the file without problem. Then I tried to change the suffix to .pdf and the error popped up again.
If I rename it to "OC0373.pdf" or "OC0372-0.pdf" there is no problem at all. And if I try to rename it after upload there is message

> "This file already exists, please choose different". There is no file with this name in library, archive or bin.

So I am thinking that this could be even Windows problem, but I tried it on Windows 7 and colleague on Windows Server 2008 R2 with same results and it shouldn't affect renaming the file in Sharepoint.
(the file is about 1.9MB)

Where is the problem? :)

Every help will be much appreciated

Comment: Did you check the correlation id in ULS logs for any further clue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the library settings -> Manage checked out files and see if there is file with the same name. I had a similar issue and in my case a different user uploaded a document with the same name and didn't checked in the file. I got the same error. Also in the ULS I got errors containing file not found and HRESULT: 0x80070002